# I want to web scrap logo teams from sofascore api

Tags: python, api, flask, web-scraping

**this is my code :**

```
import requests
import json

# Set the API endpoint URL
url = "https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/sport/football/events/live"

# Set the request headers
headers = {
    "authority": "api.sofascore.com",
    "accept": "application/json",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "referer": "https://www.sofascore.com/",
    "sec-ch-ua": "^\\^Google",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "^\\^Windows^^",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

# Send the GET request to the API endpoint
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Parse the JSON data from the response content
live_events = json.loads(response.content)

# Loop through the live events and get team logos`
for event in live_events["events"]:
    home_team_id = event["homeTeam"]["id"]
    away_team_id = event["awayTeam"]["id"]

    # Set the API endpoint URLs for each team logo
    home_team_url = f"https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/team/{home_team_id}/image"
    away_team_url = f"https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/team/{away_team_id}/image"

    # Send the GET requests to the team logo API endpoints
    home_team_response = requests.get(home_team_url, headers=headers)
    away_team_response = requests.get(away_team_url, headers=headers)

    # Parse the JSON data from the team logo response contents
    home_team_details = json.loads(home_team_response.content)
    away_team_details = json.loads(away_team_response.content)

    # Get the logo URLs for each team
    home_team_logo_url = home_team_details["url"]
    away_team_logo_url = away_team_details["url"]

    # Download the team logos
    home_team_logo_response = requests.get(home_team_logo_url, headers=headers)
    with open(f"{home_team_id}.png", "wb") as f:
        f.write(home_team_logo_response.content)

    away_team_logo_response = requests.get(away_team_logo_url, headers=headers)
    with open(f"{away_team_id}.png", "wb") as f:
        f.write(away_team_logo_response.content)
```

**this is the error that i got :**

```
File "c:\Users\Omarb\OneDrive\Bureau\PFA\TEST\logoTeam.py", line 42, in <module>
    home_team_details = json.loads(home_team_response.content)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I tried to change the 'UTF-8' encoding to 'ISO-8859-1' encoding but i still have the same msg error

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I can't help with your problem but I'm here because I need help finding a way to subscribe to the Sofascore API that you're using, I read all the documentation but i couldn't find any link or page to get access to a Sofascore API key, may I ask how did you do it?